# How can I remove the index.php for Konana based on Win OS?

Tags: windows, kohana, xampp

Hi my dev environment like this,

```
Winxp pro;
Kohana v3.03;
XAMPP Windows 1.7.3;
```

I followed the wiki guide to remove index.php file

http://kerkness.ca/wiki/doku.php?id=removing_the_index.php

But when i try to rename **example.htaccess** to **.htaccess** . Windows alert "**you must type a file name**"... Is there any solution about it?

Appreciated for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up notepad, paste in the contents provided on Kohana's site, and then navigate to your project directory and save as `.htaccess` (being sure to have *save as type* set to *all files*). You won't be able to rename to this file from windows explorer, you'll have to save it through notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the rewrite module enabled in your Apache httpd.conf file. Try uncommenting the line

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

in your conf file.

Comment: Hi Zaje, I found the line from C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf  . And the line already unconmmented after installed by default. :-)

Comment: And the window's alert **"you must type a file name"**, means windows can't allow the file which start with dot like (**.SomeApprox**). I can't follow the standard user guide to do it at Win OS.